# Unable to fetch data from local json file by axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios library for fetching data from the local json file but when i make get request it gives me error 404 not found.
Here is my file structure.

[image]

and i am using this code for fetching the data.

```
  import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class Login extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = { username: null, password: null };
  }

 handleSubmit = (e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   var username=e.target.username.value;
   var password=e.target.password.value;
   axios.get('../data.json')
   .then((res)=>{
     console.log(res.data);
   }).catch((err)=>{
     console.log(err);
   })

 }

  render(){

    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
      <input id="password" name="password" type="text" />
      <button>Login!</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

How do i solve this issue??

Comment: when you build the source does it including json files ?

Comment: no, I have included the data.json file

Comment: Some ideas: 1) Have you tried with the full path? 2) Have you tried putting your JSON in the public folder? 3) You can also simply import you JSON file if you're using webpack (>= 2.0 I believe). Tell me if anything works :)

EDIT: Didn't see @underscore's answer below. Seems that the public folder was the solution.

Answer (score 29):

If you created this file structure using **create-react-app** command you have to add your json files into public folder. then change your axios path like bellow

```
 handleSubmit = (e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   var username=e.target.username.value;
   var password=e.target.password.value;
   axios.get('./data.json')
   .then((res)=>{
     console.log(res.data);
   }).catch((err)=>{
     console.log(err);
   })
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the JSON file on the server. Try this command.

json-server -w -p 3001 data.json - runs on port 3001

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class Login extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {username: null, password: null };
  }

 handleSubmit = (e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   var username=this.refs.username.value;
   var password=this.refs.password.value;
   
    axios.get('../data.json')
    .then((res)=>{
     console.log(cb(res.data));//included the call back method
    }
    ).catch((err)=>{
     console.log(err);
    }
    )
    }

  render(){
      return(
      <form>
      <input ref="username" type="text" />
      <input ref="password" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Hope this works, tried and tested