# Accessing file in public folder through capacitor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I'm using ionic-v5, capactior and react to build an app.

I have a file (`data.json`) stored inside of my `public/` folder.

I simply want to be able to load that file in and store it as an object.

So far I have tried:

```js
import { Filesystem, FilesystemEncoding } from '@capacitor/core'

let contents = await Filesystem.readFile({
    path: "data.json",
    encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8,
})
```

```js
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

let response = await HTTP.get("file://data.json", {}, {});
ret = response.data;

return ret;
```

I have also looked at https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file but the documentation is poor to say the least.

Along with this I have tried pre-pending `/android_asset/public` to all of the paths but no luck (I know it would only work on Android, I just wanted to get something).

Comment: Try using the full path in `path` property. Also specify the directory. The example here show this: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#readfile

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Ionic React (v5) and you just want to access a file in `/myapp/public`, you don't need Capacitor.

You can use `axios` (or `fetch`).

Folder structure:

```
/myapp
    /assets
        /json
             /myFile.json
```

Sample code:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/52570060
export const fetchJsonFile = (fileName: string): Promise<any> => (
  axios.get(`./json/${fileName}`)
    .then((response) => response).catch((error) => {
      Promise.reject(error);
    })
);
```

Comment: This is not a well-formed answer. You did not explain why a file located at something like `public/myFile.json` would suddenly appear in `assets/json/myFile.json`. You also did not show how the fetching would change based on if you were on a native platform vs. a web platform.

Comment: @MahyarMirrashed This is ionic; serving out of the assets folder is a framework default, and fetching is the same regardless of native vs. web.